# How to combine non-overlapping TimeSeries

Tags: time-series

I have a list of TimeSeries which don't overlap. I want to combine them into a single TimeSeries.  They are all the same type of data from the same source (FinancialData). I read somewhere that Union might do the trick, but if I try `Union[tsList]` it doesn't do anything, while if I try `Union@@tsList` I get an error:

```
TemporalData: Options expected instead of {{{ <<<data>>>...
```

Here's a toy example:

```
portfolio1 = {"AAPL", "XOM", "GOOGL", "MSFT", "JNJ", "GE", "WFC", "JPM", "CVS", "BRK-B"};

prices1 = FinancialData[#, "Close", {{2013, 1, 1}, {2013, 01, 31}}] & /@ portfolio1;
prices2 = FinancialData[#, "Close", {{2013, 2, 1}, {2013, 02, 28}}] & /@ portfolio1;
```

The following produces no combining (which I kind of expected):

```
Union[{prices1[[1]], prices2[[1]]}]
```

But the following produces an error:

```
Union[prices1[[1]], prices2[[1]]]
```

Comment: Can you post a (toy-) example of what you have tried?

Comment: @A.G. done.....

Comment: Check out `TimeSeriesInsert`...